# How to map this JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, mapping

I tried but don't know how to read text_entries since the object is int of 0 through whatever the number. I can't make it match... What am I missing?

When I run the code, the error tells me that specie's JSON decoder expecting string but there are array, int?  I'm assuming that is where the text_entries has 0, 1, 2... for each array.  But I thought I need to match the object exactly in order to map the JSON structure.  How do you match the object when that is int and keep counting up (or down)?
What I need to access are:
id, name, url of species and text of text_entries, front of sprite (url), name of type(s).

This is my main JSON

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Joe"
    "species": {
        "name": "human"
        "url": "https://....example..."
       }
    "sprites": {
        "front": "https://...forinstance..."
        }
    "types": {
        0: {
            "slot": 1
            "type": {
                "name": "intervert"
                "url": "https://wiki.intervert"
        }
    }
}
```

Specie url leads you to another JSON...

```
{
    "text_entries": {
        0: {
            "text": "Without technologies and inventions, they are very weak physically except the certain individuals."
            "language": {
                "name":"en"
                "url": "https://wiki.english"
            }
            "version":{
                "name": "medival"
                "url": "https://wiki.medival"
            }
        }
        1: {
            "text": "Senza tecnologie e invenzioni, sono fisicamente molto deboli, tranne alcuni individui."
            "language": {
                "name":"it"
                "url": "https://wiki.italian"
            }
            "version":{
                "name": "medival"
                "url": "https://wiki.medival"
            }
        }
        2: {
            "text": "没有技术和发明，除了某些人以外，他们的身体非常虚弱。"
            "language": {
                "name":"ch"
                "url": "https://wiki.chinese"
            }
            "version":{
                "name": "medival"
                "url": "https://wiki.medival"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Swift struct.

```
import Foundation
struct List: Codable{
    let results: [Animal]
}

struct AnimalData: Codable{
    let id: Int
    let types: [AnimalTypeEntry]
    let sprites: AnimalImage
    let species: AnimalDescription
}
struct AnimalType: Codable{
    let name: String
    let url: String
}

struct Animal: Codable {
    let name: String
    let url: String
}

struct AnimalTypeEntry: Codable {
    let slot: Int
    let type: AnimalType
}

struct AnimalImage: Codable {
    let front: String
}

struct AnimalDescription: Codable {
    let url: String
}

struct Species: Codable {
    let flavor_text_entries: FlavorText
}

struct FlavorText: Codable {
    let number: DescriptionNumber
}
struct DescriptionNumber: Codable {
    let text: String
    let language: Language
    let version: String
}

struct Language: Codable{
    let name: String
}

struct Captured: Codable {
    var capturedAnimal: [String]
}
```

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/ to generate your structs

Comment: I thought that keys in JSON can only be `String`, and you have `Int`, so your JSON shouldn't be valid as such. And it's not valid as such (for other reasons). Could you post your real JSON?

Comment: @NewDev  That is definitely where my head started to twist.  It was made in right before I posted this. Do you see how confused I am?!  I still don't know what to do about those int of 0, 1, 2, 3, .... in the real JSON the number goes up until 98 or so.  I need to be able to pull out the english text.  If the language is not english, I need to move on and look at the next array.  I'm hoping to add the version info, although it's not required right now.  So I'm not so eager to fix version property.

Comment: @HarryJ, WHAT is this?! enum... huh I don't know some of them it used in the code but it is cool.  The thing is I have got to the point that I could get the data out everything except species' text.  So I rather figure out what I can fix to do get there.  But THIS IS amazing.  Thank you and I will definitely use it next time (hopefully I can figure it out :P)

Comment: @Larme, I haven't seen other complicated JSON as this so I can't say much but I see some int in this so it is possible to have int in JSON?? I don't know you tell me... https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/darkrai

Comment: You can't have `Int` as key, as value you can. And it's different. is doesn't have Int key. There is no `1: {` as you said there was. Share REAL JSON and Valid (you can shorten it, but the shorten version needs to be valid) in question (edit it, not only in comment), and five us the full error message.

Comment: @Larme, I see.  So then what you call those 0, 1, 2, 3,... containing flavor_text, language, and version? Once I get in the second URLSession to get inside species URL, I get ```typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "flavor_text_entries", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))``` So I thought this was caused because I didn't do it right in struct about the area of 0, 1, 2, 3... in flavor_text_entries...

Comment: `let flavor_text_entries: FlavorText` => `let flavor_text_entries: [FlavorText]`. You don't have a single `FlavorText`, you have multiple, hence a list, hence an array of `FlavorText`, hence `[FlavorText]`.

Comment: Is that a meaning of [ ]?  I tried to look up what it does but didn't succeed to find out.

Answer (score 1):

In Your Code :

```
struct DescriptionNumber: Codable {
    let text: String
    let language: Language
    let version: String
}
```

you define version as String , But it will be an object Type .
Try with change and be happy :)

Sample for You :

```
struct DescriptionNumber: Codable {
    let text: String
    let language: Language
    let version: Version
}

struct Version: Codable {
    let name: String
    let url: String
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks man for commenting.  It was my bad that I didn't explain well.  I actually don't need Version as the minimum requirement.  But hoping for the future improvement so I wanted to leave it there.  What I need to be able to access is the text in text_entries.  If I remove that part of the code, it works fine.  Any thoughts?